# checkSchema syntax documentation

Tags: express-validator

I would like to use the checkSchema method instead of what I am currently doing with all the checks on the post route in an array.  The problem I have is I can't find good documentation on the syntax used in the object for each key.  The doc page for schema validation (https://express-validator.github.io/docs/schema-validation.html) gives one example but no links to all the syntax that defines all the attributes you can use (isInt, toInt, isUppercase, rtrim, etc.)  I have searched high and low for the docs that tell you everything you can use there but no luck.  Can someone point me in the right place?

Answer (score 4):

express-validator is a set of express.js middlewares that wraps [validator.js](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js) validator and sanitizer functions.

you can find all the rules available in the link above.

here is a good example how it's used with checkSchema:

```
import { checkSchema, validationResult } from 'express-validator'

const schema = {
    id: {
        isFloat: true,
        // Sanitizers can go here as well
        toFloat: true,
        errorMessage: "must be a valid number"
    },
    first_name: {
        exists: {
            errorMessage: "first_name is required"
        },
        isLength: {
            errorMessage: "first_name has invalid length",
            options: {
                min: 1
            }
        }
    },
    middle_name: {
        optional: {
            options: { nullable: true, checkFalsy: true }
        }
    },
    last_name: {
        exists: {
            errorMessage: "last_name is required"
        },
        isLength: {
            errorMessage: "last_name has invalid length",
            options: {
                min: 1
            }
        }
    },
    date_of_birth: {
        isISO8601: {
            errorMessage: `date of birth is not a valid iso date`
        },
        isBefore: {
            date: "01-01-2000",
            errorMessage: `should be less than 01-01-2000`
        },
        isAfter: {
            date: "01-01-1970",
            errorMessage: `should be greater than 01-01-1970`
        }
    },
    email: {
        exists: {
            errorMessage: "email is required"
        },
        isEmail: {
            errorMessage: "email is invalid"
        }
    },
    current_country_of_residence: {
        exists: {
            errorMessage: "current_country_of_residence is required",
            options: {
                checkNull: true,
                checkFalsy: true
            }
        }
    },
    current_city_of_residence: {
        exists: {
            bail: true,
            errorMessage: "current_city_of_residence is required"
        },
        isMongoId: {
            errorMessage: "current_city_of_residence is has invalid id for"
        }
    },
    email: {
        isEmail: { errorMessage: 'email is not a valid email' },
        isLength: { errorMessage: 'email has invalid length', options: { min: 1 } }
    },
    skills: {
        isArray: {
            errorMessage: `invalid value for skills`,
            options: {
                min: 3,
                max: 5
            }
        },
        isIn: {
            options: ["java", "C++", "javascript"],
            errorMessage: `allowed values for skills are: ${["java", "C++", "javascript"]}`
        },
        custom: {
            options: (values) => {
                const unique_values = new Set(values)
                if (unique_values.size !== values.length) {
                    return Promise.reject()
                }
                return Promise.resolve()
            },
            errorMessage: `you can't add duplicated`
        },
        customSanitizer: {
            options: async (value, { req }) => {
                return value
            }
        }
    }
}
const validate = () => {
    return [
        checkSchema(schema),
        (req, res, next) => {
            const errors = validationResult(req)
            if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
                return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.mapped() })
            }
            next()
        }
    ]
}
export default validate()
```